# Continuity iff lower/upper semi continuity (using $\epsilon$-$\delta$)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, metric-spaces, epsilon-delta

The definitions that I am using are:

A real valued function $f$ defined on a metric space X is said to be continuous at $x$ iff for each $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$.

A function is said to be lower semicontinuous if $\{x : f(x) > t\} =: \{f > t\}$ is open and upper semicontinuous if $\{x : f(x) < t\} =: \{f < t\}$ is open.

**Statement**: Show that $f$ is continuous iff it is lower/upper semicontinuous.

*Sketch of work:* Let $f$ be continuous. Take $x \in \{f < t\}$. Then $f(x) < t$. Since $f$ is continuous, namely at $x$, then for $\epsilon = t - f(x) > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)| < |f(x)-t| < \epsilon$. This mean sthat $f(y)-f(x) < \epsilon$ which by adding up $f(x)$ yields $f(y) < \epsilon + f(x) = t$. Hence $y \in \{f < t\}$. A similar argument shows that $\{f > t\}$ is also open.

Now its the part that I am not sure about:

Assume that f is both lower/upper semicontinuous. Our goal is to prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$. Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $t > 0$ such that $|f(x) - t| < \epsilon/2$. Then $x \in \{f < t\}$. Since this set is open, we can find $r > 0$ such that if $y \in B(x,r) := \{a : |x-a| < r\}$ then $f(y) < t$. But then, $$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f(x)-f(y)+t-t| \leq |f(x)-t|+|f(y)-t| < \epsilon.$$In this step I used the fact that $|f(x)-t| < \epsilon$ and that the distance from $f(y)$ to $t$ must be smaller than $\epsilon$ as well because otherwise the open set would not be contained in $\{f > t\}$.

Can anyone verify if my reasoning is correct?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your definition is that of uniform continuity. Otherwise you need to add “continuous at $x$” and then $y$ is the variable in your conditional (or viceversa).

Comment: @GReyes edited. What did you find of the argument?

Comment: Did you mean to choose $t>f(x)$? Otherwise the rest doesn't really make sense

Comment: @Carlyle Why is that?

Comment: The key fact here is that the set $(x-\delta,x+\delta) = (-\infty,x+\delta) \cap (x-\delta,\infty)$.

Comment: I believe it is incorrect. For one thing, from the condition $|f(x)-t|<\varepsilon/2$ it does not follow $x\in\{f<t\}$.

Comment: Well it may not be possible to choose $t>0$ in such a way to guarantee that $$ |f(x)-t| < \varepsilon $$ try to do this for $f(x) = -2 $ and $\varepsilon = 1$.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you elaborate, plase?

Comment: @GReyes and Carlyle thank you for the pointing out!

Comment: To establish continuity at $x$, all you care about are the sets $\{y:f(y)-f(x)<\varepsilon\}$ and $\{y: f(y)-f(x)>-\varepsilon\}$, which are open and $x$ belongs to both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mistakes in your proof of the second direction of implication, firstly we cannot be guaranteed to find a $t>0$ such that

$$ |f(x)-t|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$

Since for example $f(x)$ could be very large and negative. So I'm assuming you meant to choose $t>f(x)$, since then we can also conclude $x\in\{f<t\}$

Secondly, we only know that

$$ |f(x)-t|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2} $$

And we know that there must be some open ball around $x$ which is contained in $\{f<t\}$, but every element $y$ of this open ball except $x$ could have $f(y) = t-3\varepsilon$, in which case we can't conclude that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon$. The key point is that using only upper semicontinuity is not sufficient, it should also be suspicious to you that you seemingly proved a theorem which is much stronger than the one asked in the exercise. So we suspect we need to use both upper and lower semicontinuity, and the way to do so is to also choose $t'<f(x)$ such that

$$|t'-f(x)|<\varepsilon/2$$

(in fact, one can actually just take $t'=f(x)+\varepsilon/2$ and $t=f(x)+\varepsilon/2$ ) and then to note that since both of these are open, their intersection is open, and therefore there is some open ball around $x$ which is contained in the intersection.

What can you say about the distance between any element in this open ball and $x$, when you apply $f$ to them? Can you still have for example $f(y)= f(x)-3\varepsilon$ for some $y$ in this open ball ? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, just too long for a comment.

You are using the definition of continuity at a point for continuity and the definition of global continuity for semi continuity. It is easier if you use consistent approaches.

I think the definitions that you are using hide the essential features of semi continuity.

We say that $f$ is lower semi continuous (lsc) at $x$ **iff** for all $\epsilon >0 $ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then $f(y) \in (f(x)-\delta,\infty)$.

Similarly, $f$ is upper semi continuous (usc) at $x$ **iff** for all $\epsilon >0 $ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then $f(y) \in  (-\infty, f(x)+\delta)$.

And, of course, $f$ is continuous at $x$ **iff** for all $\epsilon >0 $ there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then $f(y) \in (f(x)-\delta,f(x)+\delta)$.

Given the above, the equivalence of $f$ is continuous at $x$ **iff** $f$ is lsc. & usc. at $x$ is straightforward to see.